# Adding integer to column in database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an `integer` column on the `Users` table called `rating_number`. This number is going to consist of two things.

1. Impressions on page views
2. The total number of `likes` they have on their posts

So far, I have the impression part taken care of. I'm using the gem [is_impressionable](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) with a counter_cache like so on my **User model**:

```
is_impressionable :counter_cache => true, :column_name => :rating_number, :unique => :all
```

Now, I'm trying to add to that column the second part, which is the total number of votes they have on their posts. I am getting that integer by:

```
@user = current_user # or some user
array = @user.posts.map { |post| post.votes.count }
count = array.inject { |sum, x| sum + x }
```

where `count` is the total number of `votes` they have on their posts. How can I automatically update the `rating_number` column in an efficient way every time a User get's one of their posts `voted_on`. Should I instead go the direction where I manually add `1` to that column in the post's `def vote` action after the `vote` has successfully been saved?

Not sure if this is useful, but I'm also using the [thumbs_up](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up) gem for voting system.

Comment: In the same column 2 information you want to add ? Why not the separate columns for separate data ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure that will solve the problem here though, even if I wanted to have different columns.

Comment: I didn't ask for answering, rather why you thought that way.. The answer is very easy.. You need to use `after` hook. Whenever a post will be created, that hook method will run automatically and add votes count in the corresponding column.

Comment: Hmm..good question. From the beginning I decided to create just one column because the app's really about ranking user's based on that `rating_number`. But I guess for my purposes, I could create two columns then on the pages where I need their total score, just get the sum of the two columns. No one will be able to see that `rating_number` either. Would you mind taking a look and editing/improve the answer I submitted??

Comment: Dude use [after_create](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).. as I said in your model. And keep the information in 2 separate columns..

Comment: Yea I used the after_create in the model and it's working. If you want to submit an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookig at the your need, I am quite sure you need to use callback called [`after_update`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) in your `User` model. To understand how call back works, read [`Callbacks`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). But I would suggest you to keep the data in 2 separate columns, rather than a single column.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :vote_update

  # other methods
  def vote_update
    user = @post.user
    user.rating_number = user.rating_number + 1
    user.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: What about the race conditions?

Comment: @muistooshort Good point. I didn't think about it also. I need to think about it. Being new in Rails, still I am not much aware of all Rails features. Once I will be having an idea, I will try to add it here. For now, really I don't know.

Comment: I am a bit confused with the answer. Where do you set `@post`? `vote_update` is an `after_create` on `User`. User is just created and user already has an existing post associated to it? And I don't see `votes` being counted anywhere of `@post` in the method. It's just incrementing `rating_number` of some user by 1 and by some user I mean `user` to which `@post` belongs to. Should the method really be part of `User` model? I hope you know that `after_create` would only be called *Once per User*

Comment: @KirtiThorat That's was not about the post.. it is also not mentioned. OP was looking for a trick.. and I said and it worked.. That's it. What mu is said, is valid.. I will prepare for it latter..

Comment: You mean that setting an `after_create` on `User` would be enough to set total number of votes a "newly created user" has on all the *existing posts* of that "newly created user"?